# Capturing specific keystrokes in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent, keystroke

There are a lot of topics on how to capture keystrokes in Java Swing, but I'd like to ask about the best practice. For example, I have a window in which I wish to listen to a keystroke of either `F1` or `Command-P` on a Mac (or `CTRL-P` on a PC).

Reading [The official Javadoc for KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html), it seems that it is a better practice to use `Key Typed` events rather than `Key Pressed` or `Key Released` events, because they are higher-level. This makes sense to me, and I've even found that in order to make sure the program is platform-agnostic, I have to specify a keystroke object thusly:

```
private KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask());
```

This should allow for capturing of either the `Command` accelerator key on a Mac, and the `CTRL` accelerator key on a PC. (I hope I'm using those terms correctly.) So now that I have a `KeyStroke` object, how do I go about checking it against a `KeyEvent` object in my `KeyListener`? And throwing a check for an `F1` key event as well only complicates the matter further, though hopefully not too much.

Suggestions?

Comment: Better than `KeyListener` use [Key Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Since you already have your `KeyStroke` you have to attach it to some component's InputMap and then you'll only need an `Action` to attach it to the component's ActionMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So now that I have a KeyStroke object, how do I go about checking it against a KeyEvent object in my KeyListener?

You don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`.

Check out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) which contains a program to list the default bindings of each Swing component. It also give some example of how you might create your own `ey Bindings`. It also contains a link to the Swing tutorial on Key Bindings which explains the whole process in more detail

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the help, @camickr and @dic19. That does make things much simpler, and I can use the same `KeyStroke` object so it should respond to the correct keys on both Mac and Windows.